# How to individually scale more than one face?

Tags: edges, faces

[image][image]

I hope the images explain what I want to do, because English is not my language.

Here I have more images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe you're looking for the Pivot Point > Individual Origins option on the horizontal menu bar

Answer (score 4):

Activate the *Pivot Point* > *Individual Origins* option on the horizontal menu bar of your 3D view.

On your screenshot, the *Median Poin*t was the *Pivot Point* option selected, which means that the scale will take the median point between all your selected faces into account. *Individual Origins* will only take into account the center of each face or group of adjacent faces. And so on, if you select *3D Cursor*, it will be the pivot point of your operation...

[image]

Comment: Perhaps some form of  explanation would be handy here. Eg the result in Q is using median point. In the example with discrete unconnected faces each face will scale about its individual center (as I believe desired by OP) however could be worth noting  this changes if the faces are connected.

Comment: ok, edited, tell me if it's ok